# Two Threads seeing the same value after update

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have the following code which two threads checked if there is an element in a stack and if so they pop it. For some reason one of the two threads always gets a java.util.EmptyStackException which means its popping an empty stack. My question is shouldn't having this method be synchronized prevent this? Also is it possible to prevent my error just using synchronized methods, or will have I have to implement some sort of join/countdownlatch/cyclicbarier/etc? The reason I'm asking is because ideally I would like for only one thread to be able to access the stack plate at any given time.

```
public synchronized void checkPlate(){
        //System.out.println(this.name + " checks the plate for pancake");
        Boolean isEmpty = Producer.plate.isEmpty();
        if ( isEmpty == false){
            System.out.println(this.name + " grabs a pancake");
            Producer.plate.pop();
            eat();
            this.eatenPancakes +=1;
        }else{

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);// waits one minute seconds instead of minutes
                checkPlate();
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**
After suggestions I decided to try an implement a synchronized block on producer plate with this code. Upon doing so it looks like all my threads just freeze. Does this synchronized block needs to be added to my producer object/thread as well?

```
 public void checkPlate(){
        //System.out.println(this.name + " checks the plate for pancake");
        synchronized (Producer.plate){
            Boolean isEmpty = Producer.plate.isEmpty();
            if ( isEmpty == false){
                System.out.println(this.name + " grabs a pancake");
                Producer.plate.pop();
                eat();
                this.eatenPancakes +=1;
            }else{

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);// waits since theres no pancake
                    checkPlate();
                } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update 2** 
 Goal to Provide more information. After each thread grabs a pancake it eats/sleeps for a random amount of time with the following method. Ideally the entire program goal is to simulate where the producer constantly cooks pancakes adds it to the stack. One of the two threads check the stack and grabs a pancake if there is an element in the stack. This will happen until the producer thread is finished cooking pancakes.

```
public void eat(){
        Random ran = new Random();
        double eatingTime;
        if (this.name == "Piggy"){
            eatingTime = ran.nextDouble() * (4 - 2) + 2; //generates a value between 2 and 4
        }else{
            eatingTime = ran.nextDouble() * (5 - 3) + 3; //generates a
        }
        try {
            System.out.println(this.name + " starts eating a pancake...");
            Thread.sleep((long)eatingTime *100);//mili seconds instead of minutes
            Boolean isEmpty = Producer.plate.isEmpty();
            if (Producer.finished == false && isEmpty == false){
                checkPlate();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you didn't show the invocation part. Most importantly we have to see whether this method is invoked on the same object or on different ones.

If it calls the method from 2 different objects sharing the same resource (Producer), then you have a problem.

Looks like that's what's happening.

I also think you have another problem there. If your stack is big enough, your recursion will cause stack overflow exception.

---

UPDATE after clarifications

Essentially, synhronized method is identical to a synhronized block with monitor to be the object itself:

```
synchronized(this) {
    // code
}
```

Since you have 2 separate object, their 'this' are not the same object and they don't actually lock your resource.

Simple classic guideline for locking resources is that access has to be synchronized by the shared resource. Since you share Producer.plate, you can do:

```
synchronized(Producer.plate) {
    // code
}
```

Other objects can also be used as a monitor, but it's developer's responsibility to ensure they are properly managed to ensure synchronous access to Product.plate.

---

UPDATE to provide redone method which checks for producer to be finished cooking with no recursion.

```
public void checkPlate(){
    while(!Producer.finished)
    //System.out.println(this.name + " checks the plate for pancake");
    synchronized (Producer.plate){
        Boolean isEmpty = Producer.plate.isEmpty();
        if ( isEmpty == false){
        System.out.println(this.name + " grabs a pancake");
        Producer.plate.pop();
        eat();
        this.eatenPancakes +=1;
        }
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(200);// waits since theres no pancake
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes it is two seperate object sharing the same resource (Producer)

Comment: The problem is easily solvable then by synchronizing it by Producer.plate or another lock that ensures the shared resource is locked.

Comment: I added details to my answer.

Comment: I tried to implement your answer and all my threads just froze I updated my answer with code. It totally possible that I messed something up it's pretty late...

Comment: If it freezes with 100% CPU this means it runs something. If it freezes with 0% CPU usage, this means you have a deadlock. Deadlock means that you have 2 different locks in your system, which means in turns that you have another synchronized block or method somewhere in your code.

Comment: Actually, the way you implemented it, you're not going to have any concurrency. You will always process entire stack in one thread. The other one will find the stack empty.

Comment: The reason for that is recursion. First invocation never releases the lock before another invocation, so it just goes until it's empty and then allows another thread to get in to find it empty.

Comment: How would you recommend changing this should I move where the synchronized block is in the method, or would this be a situation where I might need to rewrite the entire method.

Comment: You will have to rewrite the method. Looks like you have another problem there. It never exits because it either eats the plate or waits for plate to be not empty. So freezing is an expected behavior here.

Comment: It's just so greedy that it always wants more food. :) Not sure what it should be doing though. That you have to tell us.

Comment: I've added another update to show the eat method an explain the goal of the entire program. I'm trying to avoid begining the guy that just posts his entire program and says something like whats wrong with it.

Comment: The problem in your code is not with synchronization. The problem is that you haven't coded an exit condition, which as described in English is when producer stops cooking. Does this mean Producer.isStopped() or something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25126/discussion-between-austin-davis-and-atrubka)

Comment: Or is it this one? Producer.finished? Then it should be somewhere in checkPlate.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is shouldn't having this method be synchronized prevent this?

You haven't given us enough information to say, basically. But if there are two *instances* of the class containing this method, then absolutely not. They will have different monitors, so can both be inside the synchronized method at the same time.

It *looks* like you're using a static variable (`Producer.plate`) as your shared queue - in which case instance-level synchronization is fundamentally not going to help you, as there *could* be multiple instances on which `checkPlate` is called.

The synchronization is probably unnecessary anyway though. Fundamentally, you should be using one of the collections in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) - these collections are *designed* for concurrent access, and are great for producer/consumer queues.

Additionally, your current code will currently recurse deeper and deeper while the plate is empty - not a good idea. If you want it to keep executing until it has consumed an item, you should use a `while` loop instead of recursion.

Comment: In this case, will using synchronized block help? As in synchronized(Producer.plate){//call to checkPlate();} ??

Comment: @AdityaJain: You *could* do that - but personally I wouldn't. I like to only synchronize on monitors where I can control the synchronization very closely - ideally private final variables within the same class which aren't used for anything *other* than serialization.

Comment: @JonSkeet Personally why don't you like to synchronize monitors that you cant control the synchronization very closely?